# 2d Array that swaps all the integers or characters in opposing rows/columns

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, char, int

I feel like I'm getting this problem turned around in my head because rows and columns are easy to mix up. Can someone help show me where I'm going wrong.

```
public static void switchRows( int[][] anArray ){
    int num = 1;

    for(int i = 0; anArray.length > i; i++){
        for(int j = 0; anArray[i].length > j; j++){
            int[][] temp = new int[anArray.length][anArray[i].length];

            temp[i] = anArray[i];
            anArray[i] = anArray[anArray.length - num];
            anArray[anArray.length - num] = temp[i];

        }
        num++;
    }       
}

public static void switchColumns( char[][] anArray ){       
    int col = 1;

    for(int i = 0; anArray.length > i; i++){
        for(int j = 0; anArray[i].length > j; j++){
            char[][] temp = new char[anArray.length][anArray[i].length];

            temp[j] = anArray[j];
            anArray[j] = anArray[anArray[i].length - col];
            anArray[anArray[i].length - col] = temp[j];

        }
        col++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. In `switchRows` we use a pivot variable `tmp` to swap the values of cell in the rows that are opposites. The expression `[anArray.length - i -1][j]` gives you the index of the cell in the opossite row but in the same column to `[i][j]`. Also notice that we iterate over the half of the rows `(anArray.length/2)` and that you don't need and extra array for the swap operation. For `switchColumns`the procedure is analogue.

```
public static void switchRows(int[][] anArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length/2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < anArray[i].length; j++) {
            int tmp = anArray[i][j];
            anArray[i][j] = anArray[anArray.length - i -1][j];
            anArray[anArray.length - i -1][j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

public static void switchColumns(char[][] anArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < anArray[i].length/2; j++) {
            char tmp = anArray[i][j];
            anArray[i][j] = anArray[i][j + anArray[i].length - 1];
            anArray[i][j + anArray[i].length - 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rows are horizontal, columns are vertical. From your description, you have something like this:

```
       COLUMN 1   | Column 2
ROW 1 |    'a'    |   'b'
ROW 2 |    'x'    |   'y'
```

With a 2d array, you will have `var myVar[ROW][COLUMN]`
So, the value of `myVar[1][2]` will be 'b', as that is `ROW 1` and `COLUMN 2`.

For this program it sounds like you need two functions.
The first one should swap the values of the rows (`switchRows`), `ROW 1` with `ROW 2`, so you will have:

```
       COLUMN 1   | Column 2
ROW 1 |    'x'    |   'y'
ROW 2 |    'a'    |   'b'
```

The value of `myVar[1][2]` will then be 'y'.

The other should function should swap the values of the  columns (`switchColumns`), `COLUMN 1` with `COLUMN 2`, so you will have

```
       COLUMN 1   | Column 2
ROW 1 |    'b'    |   'a'
ROW 2 |    'y'    |   'x'
```

The value of `myVar[1][2]` after doing that will be 'a'.

As a hint on how to do this, swapping an array inside out as described (so `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` to `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`) is the same as reversing the order of the elements inside the array. Try adding the elements to a new array, but starting at the end of the original and working to the beginning.

EDIT:
A couple other notes:
You are re-declaring your temp array each iteration through the inner `for` loop, effectively resetting it.

Also, you really only need a single function to do the actual swapping. In pseudo-code:

```
public int[] swap(int[] stuff){
   //do the swapping here
   return swappedStuff;
}

public int[][] innerSwap(int[][] stuff){
   //go through every char[] and set it equal to swap(char[])
   return innerSwappedStuff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for rows. you can play with the main for testing:

```
    public class ArrayRowSwitcher {

        public static int[][] switchRows(int[][] anArray) {
            int rows = anArray.length;
            int columns = anArray[0].length;
            int[][] result = new int[rows][columns];
            for (int i = 0; rows > i; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < anArray[i].length; j++) {
                    result[rows - i - 1][j] = anArray[i][j];
                }

            }
            return result;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[][] test = new int[][] {{1,1,1},{2,1,1},{3,1,1},{4,1,1},{5,1,1},{6,1,1}};
            int[][] result = switchRows(test);
            for (int i =0;i<test.length;i++){
                System.out.print("printing row " +i + " --> ");
                for (int j =0;j<test[0].length;j++){
                System.out.print(result[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println("-----------------");
            }
        }
    }
```